# ListView Adapter not refreshing when using search box

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity `CheckUserLocation.java`, there are 2 TextViews -

1. `chooseCityTextView` - to select a particular city from a List
2. `chooseAreaTextView` - to select a particular area belonging to that city.

When the user presses `chooseCityTextView`, a `Dialog` is created, which shows a list of cities (`singleChoice`). Currently, I am displaying 3 cities - Bangalore, Delhi, Noida.

Once the user chooses a city, the Dialog for *city* is dismissed. Then the user presses `chooseAreaTextView`, another Dialog is created, which shows a list of areas.

Both the dialogs (*city* and *area*) have a *Search Box* at the top, which can be used to search for a particular *city* or *area* (in case the List is too long). And for that I have used `TextWatcher` for both search boxes - one for *city* and another for *area* - and have used `getFilter()` in `onTextChanged()` method for both `TextWatchers`.

When the user chooses a particular city, the entire **areaList** is cleared, and new areas are added to it. 
Here is the code for that -

```
dialog_ListView_City.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//Get the city selected                    
selectedItem_City = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                chooseCityTextView.setText(selectedItem_City);

                Log.d("Selected City -", selectedItem_City);
                try {
                    //get JSON Data from Model class
                    JSONArray copyOfJSONArray = CityJSONData.getLocationJSONArray();
                    Log.e("fetched copy of", "JSONArray");
                    Log.e("size of JSON Array", "" + copyOfJSONArray.length());
                    for (int index = 0; index < copyOfJSONArray.length(); index++) {
                        Log.e("in for loop", "");
                        //get single JSON Object from the JSONArray
                        //here, each JSON Object corresponds to a CITY
                        JSONObject jsonObject = copyOfJSONArray.getJSONObject(index);

                        //each City has a CITY CODE and a CITY NAME, along with a JSON Object named "AREAS"
                        String cityName = jsonObject.getString("city_name");

                        if (cityName.equalsIgnoreCase(selectedItem_City)) {
                            Log.d("Match", "Found");
                            JSONArray areasJSONArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("areas");
                            //remove previous AREAS from List before adding NEW ones
                            areaList.clear();
                            for (int areaIndex = 0; areaIndex < areasJSONArray.length(); areaIndex++) {
                                JSONObject areaJSONObject = null;

                                areaJSONObject = areasJSONArray.getJSONObject(areaIndex);
                                //AREAS object contains "area_code" and "area_name"
                                String areaName = areaJSONObject.getString("area_name");
                                Log.e("Area Added -", areaName);
                                //also add it areaList
                                areaList.add(areaName);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Collections.sort(areaList);
                dataAdapterForArea.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialog_City.dismiss();

                chooseAreaTextView.setText("");
                chooseAreaTextView.setHint("Select Area");

            }
```

The **problem** is that when the user enters a text in the Search Bar of Area `Dialog`, filter works properly, but the adapter does not refresh the list with new *area* values even when the user selects a different city.

I don't understand why this is happening, even though I am clearing the **areaList** when a new City is selected, and also adding new values to it (which the ***Logger*** is printing, successfully).

Here is a screenshot of the problem I am having -

[image: Screenshot]

Even though the *Logger* shows new ***Area*** Values (for Bangalore) - Phase 1, JP Nagar and Phase 2, JP Nagar, the `Dialog` still shows areas for Noida (previous selection) (Sector 6, Sector 18, Sector 16).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to reassign adapter to the list because here your list is not reflection its data change.
Reasign adapter like this.

```
yourAdapterInstance = new YourAdapter(Pass here your new list. e.g areanames);
yourlistview.setAdapter(yourAdapterInstance);
```